# t-sql include inner join on a table only if records present

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a very big table with tons and tons of records.

```
[HugeTable](id, col1, col2, col3...)
```

There is a page on the front end application showing this [HugeTable] data based on many filters. One of the filters will give a subset of [HugeTable], if not null

```
#HugeTable_subset(id)
```

if this filter is present, #HugeTable_subset would have records. I would like to narrow down [HugeTable] data to only matching records in #HugeTable_subset.

so right now, in the t-sql, I am doing an if-else kind of query

```
IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM #HugeTable_subset) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT HugeTable.* FROM [HugeTable] h
        JOIN #HugeTable_subset  t
        ON h.id = t.id
        WHERE h.params = @searchParams
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [HugeTable] h
        WHERE h.params = @searchParams
    END
```

Is there a way I could merge these two selects into one?

Comment: Why is there a self-join in the 1st query? Why can't you use `SELECT h.* FROM [HugeTable] h WHERE h.params = @searchParams ;` in either case?

Comment: its not a self join. '#HugeTable_subset' is created based on some input from the front end.

Comment: If you are working on Enterprise SQL 2012 or later, I'd look into Data Table Partitioning, then using something like Case statements.

Answer (score 2):

To join the two selects in one you can just use a **LEFT OUTTER JOIN** instead of a **INNER JOIN**.
You probably already know that, yes, maybe you don't knows you already doing it in the most optimized way. sql-server ill create two sub-query plans for each select inside the IF-ELSE and use each properly.

You can acid teste it to see if there are any difference and if the IF-ELSE really beats up the LEFT JOIN option

Also there's still two point I can point out.

1) Good Indexes over the filters can really improve your performance.

2) You can use pagination to return just a few results, improving performance and user experience when the result returns a ton of records

Comment: I can't use a left outer as if #HugeTable_subset has records, then I am concerned only for those matching records from [HugeTable] for the further where clause, otherwise, I need the full [HugeTable]for the where clause. let me edit the description to make the question more clear.

Comment: I see, my fault. I don't understood that. Anyway using IF-ELSE is the recommended approach here

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT HugeTable.* FROM [HugeTable] h
    WHERE ((SELECT Count(*) FROM #HugeTable_subset) = 0) OR 
           h.id IN (SELECT t.id from #HugeTable_subset  t))
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Sorry, but my English skills are very limited. Probably the one who reads the comment, understands better the code than a possible explanation of mine in English :)